# Rotating an image view which should be inside an arc with fixed point for bottom

Tags: ios, rotation, uiimageview, uikit, core-animation

I am creating a speed gauge. The bottom of my image has to be in a center point of my arc and I need to rotate the image with a fixed center point. I don't know how to to do it.

```
    private func drawHand(center: CGPoint) {
        let handImage = UIImage(named: "hand")
        handImageView = UIImageView(image: handImage)

        handImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        handImageView.bounds = CGRect(x: center.x, y: center.y, width: 100, height: bounds.height / 3)
        handImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)

        handImageView.center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        addSubview(handImageView)
    }
```

Here is my code where I am trying to center image inside the arc but my image is in the left corner instead.

To rotation I was trying to use

```
            handImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: deg2rad(handRotation))
```

but nothing working properly.
Please help me with settting my image in the center of arc and then rotating its.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line:

```
handImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
```

you've set the anchor point to the **Left Edge** and **Vertical Center**

Change it to this:

```
// set the anchorPoint to Horizontal Center / Bottom Edge
handImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
```

and see if you get the rotation you want.

Here's a complete example... the arrow starts at Zero-degrees (pointing up) -- each tap will increment the rotation by 10-degrees:

```
extension Double {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { self * 180 / .pi }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var handImageView: UIImageView!
    
    var handRotation: Double = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let handImage = UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up")
        handImageView = UIImageView(image: handImage)
        
        // so we can see the image view frame
        handImageView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        view.addSubview(handImageView)
        
        // set imageView frame to 80 x 160
        handImageView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 80, height: 160))
        
        // set the anchorPoint to Horizontal Center / Bottom Edge
        handImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        
        // set image view's Anchor Point to the center of the view
        handImageView.center = view.center
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // increment rotation by 10-degrees with each touch
        //  Zero-degrees is pointing UP (12 o'clock)
        handRotation += 10
        handImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(handRotation.degreesToRadians))
        print("rotation:", handRotation)
    }

}
```